# Date cannot be in the future SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm trying to add a kind of constraint that will prevent the user from entering dates in the future, I need it to raise an error when the user tries to do so.

This is what I have so far:

```
Create Procedure CustomerBooks (@month int, @year int)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT     
       SaleNumber, 
       month(saledate) as SaleMonth, year(saledate) as SaleYear,
       CustomerNumber, EmployeeNumber, SubTotal, GST, Total
    FROM         
       sale
    Where  
       month(saledate) = @month 
       and YEAR (saledate) = @year 
End

If salemonth > GETDATE(Month(saledate))  
   or saleyear > GETDATE(YEAR(saledate))
begin
   Raiserror ('Invalid entry, you cannot enter future dates',16,1)
end


EXEC dbo.CustomerBooks @month = '1', @year = '2012'
```

Comment: what issue are u facing?

Comment: the code just doesn't seem to work i keep getting this error "Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CustomerBooks, Line 32
The getdate function requires 0 argument(s)."

Comment: Getdate() will not accept any parameters.Getdate() and Now() will indeed only give you the current date.

Comment: so what would i have to do inorder to make it work?

Comment: my 2 cents....checks like should be done using client side javascript or your serverside language asp/php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, the simplest solution would be to add a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to prevent anyone entering a date beyond the (SQL Server) system date.

```
ALTER TABLE Sale ADD CONSTRAINT CKC_SALE_SALEDATE CHECK (SaleDate <= GetDate());
```

---

**Edit 1** *Regarding OP's comment on adding a check constraint to a stored procedure*

The benefit of a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`is that it can't be bypassed without disabling it.

There will always be instances where someone inserts/updates the data without going through the stored procedure you've set up. The constraint will prevent entering incorrect data.

---

**Edit 2** *Regarding OP's error when checking on GetDate()*

The following construct currently doesn't compile

```
   If salemonth > GETDATE(Month(saledate))  
   or saleyear > GETDATE(YEAR(saledate))
```

The error message hints to what is in error here, the GetDate() function doesn't take any parameters. Most likely, I suspect you meant to write something like this

```
   If salemonth > MONTH(GetDate())  
   or saleyear > YEAR(GetDate())
```

---

**Edit 3**

Verify that the inputs are not in the future could be done by using following if/then/else construct. Another option would be to convert the inputs to an actual date and check on that.

```
IF (YEAR(GetDate()) < @year)    
  Raiserror ('Invalid entry, you cannot enter future dates',16,1)
ELSE IF (YEAR(GetDate()) = @year) AND (MONTH(GetDate()) < @month) 
  Raiserror ('Invalid entry, you cannot enter future dates',16,1)
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02138/1)

Comment: okay but can check constraints be added to a stored procedure?

Comment: @Shahze123 - No but that's the point. There's no need to. It can't be bypassed *(without disabling it)* like a stored procedure can.

Comment: I understand that but i'd like it so that i can raiserror whenever someone tries to enter a future date

Comment: @Shahze123 - I don't know your exact use case but the check constraint will fail the transaction, wether it is through a stored procedure or direct SQL. Your client will receive an exception at which point you decide on how to handle that. If for educational purposes you insist on using a raiserror in a stored procedure, you can catch the exception raised by the check constraint and reraise it in the stored procedure but personally, I would find that overkill.

Comment: okay so how would i go about adding a check constraint to the original tabl, then catching the exception raised by it and lastly reraise it in the procedure

Comment: @Shahze123 - You can copy/paste the add check constraint line in my answer to add the check constraint to your table. That said, your current procedure doesn't align with what you say you want to do. You say you don't want the user to enter future dates but your current procedure (tries to) checks the already existing dates in the table and nowhere inserts data.

Comment: okay so how would i go about doing this, i'm new to sql server the original question in my text book is

6.Write a procedure CustomerBooks that displays the amount spent on books purchased by each customer, who purchased books, during a certain month.The month is passed into the procedure as an integer month and an integer year.  Error messages are required for the following:  The month number is valid (1 – 12) 
  The month and year are not in the future.

Comment: @Shahze123 - I have added an example to my answer but any further questions really should go into opening another question on SO.

Comment: thanks your answer helped and i tried using the check constraint both work and your explination and method of doing this is alot easier and very clear, unlike the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a trigger Instead.**

```
Create or replace trigger tri_name
before insert on  sale 
begin
If salemonth > GETDATE(Month(saledate)) or saleyear > GETDATE(YEAR(saledate))
then 
Raiserror ('Invalid entry, you cannot enter future dates',16,1)
end;
/
```

**May be this will help You.**

Comment: how would i add this to my code tho? it has to be a stored procedure and i haven't learned triggers just yet so i'm unsure as to how i can use it