# Make column value less than or equal than current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I need to make sure the entry of one of my columns lets call it `CreationDate` is =< current date.

After failing trying to use this

```
CHECK ( CreationDate =< GETDATE())
```

For the reasons mentioned in this post:
[CHECK constraint on date of birth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424900/check-constraint-on-date-of-birth?lq=1)

I'm wondering how would I write a Trigger for SQL Server that will check if the date im trying to insert/update is =< currentDate

I have never used triggers before, I came out with this, but I'm not sure if it works, or how will it be called. 
I'm trying to make the trigger return an error so that the programmer is forced to check or fix this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckValidDateTrigger
ON Reports
INSTEAD OF
UPDATE
AS    
DECLARE @ReportCloseDate DateTime;  

  IF (@ReportCloseDate > GETDATE())
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Error, the date your trying to save cannot be higher or newer that the current date. The date must be in the past or be the current date', -- Message text.
               16, -- Severity.
               1 -- State.
               );
  END;
```

Can you guys help me out a little?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803002/date-cannot-be-in-the-future-sql) has a similar trigger sample in the last answer.

Comment: Did you try `CHECK (CreationDate < GETDATE())` or `CHECK (CreationDate <= GETDATE())`? `=<` is invalid syntax and the link you point to refers to Oracle.

Comment: Should have test it before asking yes it works sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says *any* expression that evaluates to TRUE or FALSE:

> CHECK constraints enforce domain integrity by limiting the values that
>   are accepted by one or more columns. You can create a CHECK constraint
>   with any logical (Boolean) expression that returns TRUE or FALSE based
>   on the logical operators.

There is not a restriction (as far as I've found) on non-deterministic functions (that is, on functions where the same call may return different values at different times).

The example that you point to is tagged Oracle.  It also gives an alternative solution which is to add a column whose default value is `getdate()` and to check against that.

So, your `check` constraint as intended should work.

Comment: @Gordon - when you say "volatile" you actually mean non-deterministic. Also the check constraint as written won't work - `=<` is not the same as `<=`. Only one of those forms is valid.